# Django best practice - referencing custom user or profile model

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

Based on Django's recommendation that [information should be stored in a separate model if it's not directly related to authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), I've created both a custom user model and a profile model in my app.

Something like:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='email address',
            max_length=255,
            unique=True
            )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'date_of_birth']

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', 
                              default='default.jpg')
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                           choices=(('Male', 'Male'),
                                    ('Female', 'Female'),
                                    ('No Comment', 'No Comment')),
                           default="No Comment")
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

What's the best practice for having other models refer to a user? For example, my app has a messaging system. In the `Message` model, is it best to have a foreignkey relation to `Profile` as opposed to `User`? Should the `User` model only be used for the purpose of authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can relate the models to User and use related name to access profile.

This makes your models not depend directly on custom profile.

Comment: yeah, user will always be available, and then you can check profile's existence and act accordingly